# What are the names of the white matter tracts in the cortico-ventral basal ganglia circuit?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

I am looking at diffusion tensor imaging (DTI) data. The data are clustered by regions of interest (ROIs). The clusters have locations with names, which I have listed below.

**Which location names refer to white matter (WM) tracts or regions in the cortico-ventral basal ganglia circuit (CVBGC)?**

The CVBGC includes the orbitofrontal cortex (OFC), ventromedial prefrontal cortex (vmPFC), ventral striatum (VS), ventral pallidum (VP), and dorsal anterior cingulate cortex (dACC). You may know the CVBGC by other names, such as the frontostriatal system, the reward system, or perhaps the salience network.

I have attempted to answer this question myself, but the sources I have examined either fail to explicitly name any of the WM tracts connecting the areas of the CVBGC, or in the case of the DTI atlases, do not state which areas are connected by each tract with enough clarity for me to answer my question. Furthermore, some of the location names in the DTI data I have are regions rather than WM tracts (e.g. the middle frontal gyrus), and may be synonymous with the CVBGC area names I have listed above, but it is not clear to me if they are synonymous.

If you give a full or partial answer to my question, please include a citation in your response.

- anterior corona radiata (ACR)
- cingulum (cingulate gyrus) (CGC)
- cerebellar hemisphere (CH)
- cerebral peduncle (CP)
- inferior frontal gyrus (IFG)
- inferior fronto-occipital fasciculus (IFO)
- inferior temporal gyrus (ITG)
- internal capsule (IC)
- middle cerebellar peduncle (MCP)
- middle frontal gyrus (MFG)
- medial lemniscus (ML)
- middle temporal gyrus (MTG)
- posterior thalamic radiation (PTR)
- superior cerebellar peduncle (SCP)
- superior corona radiata (SCR)
- superior frontal gyrus (SFG)
- superior longitudinal fasciculus (SLF)
- supramarginal gyrus (SMG)
- uncinate fasciculus (UNC)